# Monitor (plugin) detection from Javascript

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, multiple-monitors

I would like to open a popup window on an other screen than the actual (if it is possible).

Question A: Is it possible to detect somehow from JavaScript when an other monitor was plugged in to your current machine?

Question B: Is it possible to detect the available monitors from JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe by monitoring the `window.screen` property?  This sounds like a fun challenge, working on a JSFiddle right now :)

Comment: I want to be careful to say outright "no" to your questions just yet (still working), but so far this is the best I have been able to do: http://jsfiddle.net/E9nuF/ (just to detect when the browser moves between two screens and only if they have different resolutions.  It appears that JavaScript only sees the screen that the current window appears in.